# Nhibernate - partial loading of bags using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fetch, bag

I have this:

```
class Car:Entity { string Make { ... } ICollection<Wheel> Wheels { ... } 
  ... tons of props ... }

class Wheel:Entity { Car Car { ... } int Number { ... } int Size { ... } 
  ... tons of props ... }
```

I want to get list cars with makes and wheels numbers only:

```
var data =
  this.Repository.Data
    .Select(x => new Allocation
    {
      Make = x.Make,
      Wheels =
        x.Wheels
          .Select(a =>
            new Wheel
            {
              Number = a.Number,
              Size = a.Size,
            })
          .ToArray(),
    })
    .Take(60)
    .ToArray();
```

However, this fails because it produces a sub-query for the wheels and it either has 2 columns (when I add another column for the Wheel) or more than one record (obviously since Wheels is a collection). The "fetch" attribute on the  mapping is ignored. **Query**:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
select TOP (@p0)  
        car0_.Make as col_0_0_, 
        (select 
                wheel1_.Number, 
                wheel1_.Size 
            from dbo.Wheels wheel1_ 
            where car0_.Id=wheel1_.CarId) as col_1_0_ 
    from dbo.Cars car0_ 
',N'@p0 int',@p0=60
```

Any suggestions? I'd like to keep this in LINQ for abstraction.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: @DavidC See the question... I get either "subquery can't have 2 columns" when getting Number and Size, or when only getting Number, "subquery returned more than 1 row", both standard and expected SQL Server errors for the queries that NHibernate produces. See question update for the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOP 60 probably won't do what you think it does here

```
var query = from car in Repository.Data
            from wheel in car.Wheels
            select new { car.Id, car.Make, wheel.Number, wheel.Size };

var data = query
    .Take(60)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Id, (key, values) => new Allocation
    {
      Make = values.First().Make,
      Wheels = values.Select(a => new Wheel
          {
              Number = a.Number,
              Size = a.Size,
          })
          .ToArray(),
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Update: to load exactly 60 root entities and initialize more than one collection

```
var cardata = Repository.Data.Select(car => new { car.Id, car.Make }).Take(60).ToList();

foreach(var c in cardata)
{
    var carId = c.Id;
    a.Wheels = aRepository.Data.Where(c => c.Id == carId).SelectMany(car => car.Wheels).Select(w => new Wheel { Number = w.Number, Size = w.Size}).ToFuture();

    a.Foos = aRepository.Data.Where(c => c.Id == carId).SelectMany(car => car.Foos).Select(f => new Foo { Bar = f.Bar }).ToFuture();
}

cardata[0].Wheels.Any();  // execute the futures
return cardata;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already, but other than TOP 60 not working (which I need), another problem would be if I wanted to load another sub-collection. I guess the moral of the story is, for "Search" operations, always write a proc.

Comment: write a proc or use more than one roundtrip

Comment: Using more than one roundtrip as the solution for now.

Comment: with the futures there are only 2 roundtrips

Comment: Good thing to know about ToFuture. I'm actually doing something similar to that but using in-memory dictionary to add the wheels to their appropriate cars.